# modify project in asp.net 1.1 in vs 2010

Tags: asp.net

i have a project that is developed in asp.net 1.1. But i have vs 2010 installed...can i modify,debug and deploy from vs 2010...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

yes you can modify , debug, deploye your project in VS2010.

Comment: can u pls give an example of how i can add the project... debug it and how to deploy it as 1.1 project

Comment: No need to do anything , VS2010 will automatically use .net1.1 once you click your project file, though it asks you to convert that project to a newer version, but just click no on that dialogue.

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET 1.1 is not supported with VS 2010. So, if you want to debug and deploy, you will need to at least convert it to 2.0+

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff956194.aspx

This will probably break some things like relative links in your existing project.